# How to find out what digits are missing in an IntStream

Tags: java, algorithm, java-stream

I want to return a string consisting of those digits (in ascending order) that do not appear in any of the argument numbers. I don't know how this should be done, but I would like to use the long as a comparator to find out the missing digits in IntStream.

For example, if **numeros** = [1201, 23045], I must return **"6789"**

My code:

```
public static String digitosQueNoEstanEn(List<Long> numeros)
{
    long n = 1234567890;
    IntStream numStream = numeros.stream()
        .map(c -> c.toString())
        .flatMapToInt(c -> c.chars())
        .distinct();
```

Comment: `long n = 1234567890;` this is rather wrong

Comment: Using a `BitSet` might be a good approach.

Answer (score 5):

There are many solutions to this problem, one of which is a simple set removal. You essentially want to remove all used digits from the set of valid digits, and store the result as a `String`. That can be done with the following:

```
public static String digitosQueNoEstanEn(List<Long> numeros) {
    Set<Integer> usedDigits = numeros.stream()
                                     .map(String::valueOf)
                                     .flatMapToInt(String::chars)
                                     .map(c -> Character.digit(c, 10))
                                     .boxed()
                                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return IntStream.range(0, 10)
                    .filter(i -> !usedDigits.contains(i))
                    .sorted()
                    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

When invoked with your example of `[1201L, 23045L]`, the output is what you expect:

```
6789
```

---

Andy Turner also mentioned that [using a `BitSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843621/how-to-find-out-what-digits-are-missing-in-an-intstream/59843946#comment105821407_59843621) may be a viable solution. If you choose to use one, your solution may look like the following:

```
public static String digitosQueNoEstanEn(List<Long> numeros) {
    BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { 0b0011_1111_1111 });

    numeros.stream()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .flatMapToInt(String::chars)
        .map(c -> Character.digit(c, 10))
        .forEach(bitSet::clear);

    return bitSet.stream()
                 .sorted()
                 .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: The show me this: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long

Comment: @AlaeOundir On which line? If you copy the code straight from the answer, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.

```
        public static String digitosQueNoEstanEn(List<Long> numeros) {
           String digits = "0123456789";
           return numeros.stream()
                .flatMap(numero->Arrays.stream(Long.toString(numero).split("")))
                .distinct()
                .reduce(digits, (dgts,d)->dgts.contains(d) ? dgts.replace(d,"") : dgts);
         }

         List<Long> numeros = List.of(1201L, 23045L);
         digitosQueNoEstanEn(numeros);  
         System.out.println(result);
```

> 6789

Basically I flatten the list of supplied numbers to digits and then just remove them in a reducing operation.  What is left are the digits that were not in the original numbers.